# Android TextView inside RadioGroup Not Exactly Fitting

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I do try to get text datas from JSON, i do. But when it is time to write they are not exactly fitting. My XML file is here...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_questionAdjective"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="139dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
    <RadioGroup
     android:id="@+id/grp_options"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdb_optionA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_optionA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdb_optionB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_optionB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdb_optionC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_optionC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdb_optionD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_optionD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

And what it looks like after that.
[image]

How can i set C and D options next to radiobuttons ? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:SOLVED** I deleted the textView parts in XML and used the for loop which @Gabriella Angelova provided me. That really helped. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not setting text to radiobuttons??

Comment: Because the textview's data is parsed from JSON. Is there anyway to make setText inside the radiobutton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code snipet to set the text of your radio buttons dynamically:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.grp_options);

for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup .getChildCount(); i++) {
        ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i)).setText(*your value from JSON*);
    }
```

Comment: RadioButton can not be resolved a type. 
Actually if you tell me how to fit my text near the radiobutton, not below, it will be enough too.

Comment: Add the following line to the top of your class, along with the other imports:

`import android.widget.RadioButton;` and it will be resolved

Else if you find the specific position (for example margin 50dp on the top or something else) i will be a solution only for one display size, not for all, so it is better to use the code I provided to you with the import of course

Comment: Okay when i used the loop properly it solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
radioButton.setText("your text");
```